# Why can't Typescript infer prop type when using Generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the code below:

```js
interface MyInterface {
   a: {
     b: {
       c: "c";
    };
  };
}

type ParentProps = keyof MyInterface
type ChildProps<ParentProp extends ParentProps> = keyof MyInterface[ParentProp]

type GrandChildType<ParentProp extends ParentProps, ChildProp extends ChildProps<ParentProp>> =
  MyInterface[ParentProp][ChildProp]['c']
```

I'm getting an error in the `GrandChildType` saying:

> Type '"c"' cannot be used to index type
> 'MyInterface[ParentProp][ChildProp]'.(2536)

However, if I change the last line to:

```js
type GrandChildType<ParentProp extends ParentProps, ChildProp extends ChildProps<ParentProp>> =
  MyInterface[ParentProp][ChildProp]

type test = GrandChildType<'a', 'b'>['c']
```

then I properly get the type of `c` which is `"c"`. So, the question is: why can't I get that value type when using Generics if both `ParentProps` and `ChildProps` are keys extracted from `MyInterface`?

reproducible link: [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlS4AuQk00gI0uJqYUoCIFWBua0gX277deRImHQAHFAAU4UCOClQA9uIDOyALzIA1hHRKYaLDliIIoiSgDCAC2AAbACaKVqgDwy5C5eOQQAHpAgjuqe8mAuagB8mjp6BkbYkKZIANph3ioAuiIA9LnIYHbqCEqOKI5KEKogAORgyADuSlDaFpLIAOJQcMG2Do4AKpYesuGRfoHyIcgZET6qADTI-U4TAUEzq84Lo17zKlExGtQYSbhm6WOZ4lmp25F3tQi1OUT5yLQQ9vZKjcilcpNFraVTvApiDrdXqObbDSR7cY+SabULXA5qZYPZEbabqbGuRE3I6acE0M4mPAQK77R73OxrHxvD6QlCQVQNLTQvoMoYjWpwWrLWq0WpRVLPV5AA)

Comment: Looks like a bug in TypeScript, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27709 . If you're looking for workarounds you can usually `Extract` out something appropriate like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE5K2w).  Does this answer your question or am I missing something?

Comment: thank you SO much @jcalz, your workaround worked nicely, you can make it as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Okay, I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#27709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27709) for details.  Nested generic [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) types seem to "forget" their constraint and won't let you index into them with a specific key anymore.  The bug has been open for a long time with no sign that it will be addressed soon, so you might want to work around it.

In cases where you have a type `T` where you know `T extends U` is true but the compiler doesn't, you can often replace `T` with `Extract<T, U>` using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  The compiler will accept that `Extract<T, U> extends U`, and assuming you're correct about `T extends U`, then eventually (when the generics are specified), `Extract<T, U>` will evaluate to just `T`.  (Note that this is an "off-label" use of `Extract<T, U>` which is used primarily to filter unions in `T` to just those members which are assignable to `U`.)

In order to index into some type `T` with the key type `"c"`, it means the type should be assignable to `{c?: any}`.  If `T["c"]` fails to compile, then `Extract<T , {c?: any}>` should succeed. Let's try it here:

```
type GrandChildType<K extends keyof MyInterface, K2 extends keyof MyInterface[K]> =
  Extract<MyInterface[K][K2], { c?: any }>['c']; // okay

type C = GrandChildType<"a", "b"> // "c"
```

Looks good! The type of `GrandChildType<"a", "b">` is `"c"` as desired, and the error in `GrandChildType` is gone.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlk4AuQ5AI0oOQUoCIEnkBfDo9oosdAA4oA4lDggAJgGEAFsAA2EgCqCIAHgDSyCAA9IkgM7IA1hHQB7GGiw5YiCABpkGgEza9EQybOXr2SHZIANoaALoAfMgAvCR+tngQIaEhLskA5AhpocgA9DnaUFDmUACEvPxCyKLi0nKKKkIumu76EkamFlYY-rj2Tq4tnm3enXEBCUmRMaQAonpiCGBq3fH2SSmhTvQIAPyU4ugc4UEZWeWqyFLRVWKSsgrKqk1McExOTNRMkXnILExAA)

Comment: thanks sir, very useful answer!